# RedBeanPHP: UTF8 vs UTF8MB4 issue - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: redbean

My problem is described here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redbeanorm/z8SD3qeMEM4/eROS7wBBtccJ

But I can't reply to the post. It just gets deleted every time. In any case, I'm hoping someone here has run across this.

---

Precondition: No table named 'my_table' exists

Code:

```
    $bean = R::dispense('my_table');
    $bean->setMeta("buildcommand.unique", array(array('barcode')));
    $bean->barcode = '000000000000000000';
    $bean->date_created = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    R::store($bean);
```

Postcondition:

"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes"

---